# LINQ - Select anonymous type which based on a collection property

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Class:

```
public class DistributionItem
{

    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public double? Export { get; set; }
    public double? Import { get; set; }
    public List<double?> Tarrifs { get; set; }
    public bool HasChild { get; set; }
    public int OrderNum { get; set; }
    public double PF { get; set; }
    public int? MaxDmd { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public double? Total { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make a LINQ `Select` over a List of this class to pull-out some of the properties like this:

```
        return data.Select(x => new
        {
            x.DeviceID,
            x.DeviceName,
            x.HasChild,
            x.KwhImport,
            x.KwhExport,
            x.MaxDmd,
            x.ParentID
        }).ToList();
```

How can I add the `Tarrifs` values as separate properties to the anonymous object?

Comment: Why would you want to restrict the number of items like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, unless you know the number of items in the list at compile time.  The idea of anonymous types is that they're *statically typed*.  The compiler knows, at compile time, what all of the properties and their types are.  You can't use one if you don't know that information.

If you know that there are, for example, always two items, then you can do something like:

```
return data.Select(x => new
{
    x.DeviceID,
    x.DeviceName,
    x.HasChild,
    x.KwhImport,
    x.KwhExport,
    x.MaxDmd,
    x.ParentID,
    Tarrifs1 = x.Tarrifs[0],
    Tarrifs2 = x.Tarrifs[1],
}).ToList();
```

Comment: So, What should be a adequate solution to such an issue? regular iteration?

Comment: @ronen You probably just want to leave it as a collection, rather than having multiple variables.  As to how to use that collection when using the results of the query, that I can't say, as I don't know what you're doing with it.

Comment: @ronen I'll repeat has already been said. Why would you want to restrict the number of items and to flatten the Tarrifs collection?

Comment: That doesn't really tell me enough to give you an answer.  As I said, either you have a known number of items in the list, and you can do what I showed you, or you don't, and you're better off leaving it as a collection and handling that collection further on down the line.